# Creating Custom option and prize to just added product to wishlist using observer

Tags: magento

I want to add custom option to quoteitem using observer which observer wishlist_product_add_after event and fires after product added to Wishlist.

```
public function wishlistProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
     $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'wishlist_index_add'){ 
        //What we do now if my custom options are like shape, material,symbol which is coming more then one in array
    }
```

My observer is working but i am not able to add custom option to added wishlist . please provide help to add custom option using observer to just added wishlist. 
    }